# How to check if the second list element on a line in a file contains 'x'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

What I'm trying to do is to create a login system. 
I ask the user for a username, and if that username is in the file, I want to ask for a password.

But I don't know how I could check if the username and password matches.

The file with usernames is formated like this:

```
Username1 Password
Username2 Password
```

My code is:

```
def login():
    users = open('passwords.txt', 'r').readlines()
    while x == 1:
        usernames = [i.split()[0] for i in users]
        username = raw_input("> ")
        if username.lower() in usernames:
            password = raw_input("> ")


        else:
            print 'That username is not in use.'
```

So the question is, **how may I check if I.E: Password matches with Username1**? 
I know I can't loop through, every password in the file like this:

```
passwords = [i.split()[1] for i in users]
```

Because, then it would accept every single password in the file, and not the matching one only.

Comment: You could use dictionaries to store the password of each user: `{i.split()[0]:i.split()[1] for i in l}`? Then you can check if user exist with `if username.lower() in d.keys()` and verify password with `password == d[username]`.

Comment: @fredtantini `That's an answer not a comment` :P

Comment: @BhargavRao It wasn't at first, just a suggestion "use dict" and then, I got carried away :þ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use dictionaries to store the password of each user:

```
dictPass = {i.split()[0]:i.split()[1] for i in users}
```

Then you can check if a user exist with

```
if username.lower() in d:
```

and verify password with

```
if password == d[username.lower()]:
```

or

```
if password == d.get(username.lower()):
```

---

Another way is to find the index of the user:

```
whichUser = usernames.index(username.lower())
```

and then, using `passwords = [i.split()[1] for i in users]` you can get the password with:

```
realPassword = passwords[whichUser]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about using dicts, but I wasn't exactly sure how I could do that.

Comment: using `in d.keys()` is `O(n)` just use `in d`.

Comment: Or simply `if password == d.get( username.lower() )`.  Also `.index` would do a linear scan so not really recommended...

Comment: also iterating over the file object  and using with to open the file would be better

Comment: @fredtantini, no worries